# Codeigniter internationalization library how to save user's language choice

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

I am using this multilanguage addon http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CodeIgniter_2.1_internationalization_i18n to make available my codeigniter sites in various idioms.

I have this php code with echo links to change the language

```
echo anchor($this->lang->switch_uri('en'),'English | ');
echo anchor($this->lang->switch_uri('es'),'Español | ');
echo anchor($this->lang->switch_uri('ro'),'Română');
```

It does the change with no problem, but it doesn't remember it. When I change page, from home to about, will go back to browser's language or Romanian if browser's language is not defined.

So, what could go wrong? What and how should I do to remember that choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply change the choice by using the session:

`$this->session->set_userdata('language', 'en');`

See more details about using [session data](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)
Later refer to what the users choice is by calling:

`$language = $this->session->userdata('language ');`

Comment: where should I define these sessions?

Comment: ... in your controller, just see the example link provided, you should have an understanding of how to use them through reading the userguide for CI. All your info is there, just need to read through it.

Comment: so that means that I have to define this for each and one of my controllers? now it's ok, but later is going to be hell... pfff.

Comment: changed the system of the internationalization feature, but tnx